# How to implement details screen that dynamically displays detail of pokemon when a user presses on a picture in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, react-native, user-interface

So I have built a pokemon application that would display pokemon with their images and details. On the homescreen, I have it so that the first 20 pokemon are shown as a preview. Then if the user wants to learn more about the pokemon, they can press on the pokemon and it would bring the user to the "PokeDetails" screen. However, when I press on the pokemon, it brings me to the "PokeDetails" page but the page is blank. Except for the text that I explicitly render from the "PokeDetails" screen. I have the code for both screens below. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

```
  //Home.js

    import React, { useState } from "react";
    import { View, Text , Button, FlatList, ActivityIndicator, TouchableOpacity, Image } from "react-native";
    import { GlobalStyles } from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
    import PokeDetails from "./PokeDetails";



    class Home extends React.Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                isLoading: true,
                dataSource: [],
            }
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20`)
                .then((res)=> res.json())
                .then((response)=> {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoading: false,
                        dataSource: response.results,
                    })
                    console.log("RESPONSE",response)
                    console.log("RESPONSE.RESSSULTS",response.results)
                })

        }

        render() {
            const showIndicator = this.state.isLoading == true ? <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" /> : null;
            return(
                <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
                    <View style={GlobalStyles.activityIndicator}>{showIndicator}</View>
                    <FlatList 
                        numColumns={1}
                        data={this.state.dataSource} 
                        renderItem={({item})=> 
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("PokeDetails", {item} )}>
                            <PokeDetails imageUrl={`https://projectpokemon.org/images/normal-sprite/${item.name}.gif`} name={item.name} item={item} />
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        }/>
                    <Button onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate("About")} title="Go to about"/>
                </View>
            )
        }
    }


    export default Home;



    // PokeDetails.js

   import React from "react";
import { View, Text , Image, Button} from "react-native";
import {GlobalStyles} from "../styles/GlobalStyles";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';



const PokeDetails =({name, imageUrl, detail, route})=> {

    return(
        <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>  
                <Text>This text is written expilictly</Text>
                <Text>{route.params.item}</Text>
        </View>
    )
}


export default PokeDetails;


    // Root.js

    import React from "react"
    import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
    import Home from "../screens/Home";
    import PokeDetails from "../screens/PokeDetails";
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';



    const Root =() => {
        const Stack = createStackNavigator();
        return(
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home}/>
                <Stack.Screen name="PokeDetails" component={PokeDetails}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        )
    }


    export default Root;



    // App.js


    import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import React from 'react';
    import { View , StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
    import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
    import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
    import About from "./screens/About";
    import Root from "./Route/Root";
    import PokeDetails from "./screens/PokeDetails"



    const App =()=> {

      const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Drawer.Navigator>
              <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Root}/>
              <Drawer.Screen name="About" component={About}/>
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        </View>
      )
    }


    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1
      }
    })



    export default App;
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understood your question. You already pass an `item` props to your `PokeDetails` component from your Homescreen, but there is no `item` in the props your receive in it. just add it and i guess you will access to your data and will be able to display it:

```
const PokeDetails =({name, imageUrl, detail, item})=> {
    return(
        <View style={GlobalStyles.container}>
            <Image source={{uri: imageUrl}} style={{height: 50, width: 50}}/>
            <Text style={GlobalStyles.pokeText}>{name}</Text>
            <Text>This text is explicitly written</Text>
            // add your stuff here...
            <Text>{item.something}</Text>

        </View>
    )
}
```

By the way, since you already have the `item` prop, you can remove the `name` which already comes from item :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! The thing is I have two different screens. The first picture is homescreen where I just want to display a preview of 10 pokemon. Then when the user presses on an individual pokemon, it brings me over to the PokemonDetails(second picture) screen where the information for that individual pokemon is displayed. However, the information is not being displayed there for some reason even though it is in that component where I write all the information. Thanks again!

Comment: @kennyman335 Ok well maybe you can try to pass item as route param when you navigate to your PokeDetails. Just add item as params: `navigation.navigate('Pokedetails', {item});` and then in your PokeDetails screen you can add route in your props `const PokeDetails =({name, imageUrl, detail, route})=> {...}`. You will have access to your item in `route.params.item` or `[item} = route.params` depending on your prefered syntax ;) Let me know if it works i'll edit the answer

Comment: Hi Quentin, thank you for taking the time to answer. I have done what you said but got an error: "undefined is not an object(evaluating route.params)". I believe it has something to do with me having two different navigators (a stack navigator in Root.js and a drawer navigator in App.js that nests the stack navigator) I have added the code for those files if you want ton check it out. Thanks again!

Comment: Hi @kennymann335, first you should change the name of one of your "Home" screen, it's pretty disturbing haha but i don't thinkit has something to do whith your problem. Can you try doing `navigation.navigate('PokeDetails', {screen:'PokeDetails', params:{items}});` please ?

Comment: Hey Quentin, thank you for your suggestions :) . I have implemented it but still the route.params is undefined for some reason. Really weird

Comment: Well sorry but I won't be of any help now :/ I tried to reproduce a sample on snack.expo but even the basics are not working. The last thing you can try is to remove the second navigator. This way you will see if your implementation of the nested navigators is in cause. I've never tried nested navigators (Started playing with react-native a week ago) but i don't see anything different from the official doc. Maybe you can start from scratch while following/reading it (https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started)

Comment: Alright. Thank you for your help and good luck with your coding journey!